# Namespace list to directory structure

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

## Namespace list to directory structure

### Motivation

I have a list of namespaces I extracted from types, and I which to create a directory structure, that represents these namespaces. So that I can place a file at the namespace path of each type.
The simplest method would be to replace the `.` separator with a `\\`, and call it a day. But I want to be fancy, so I set myself the goal to minimize the number of directories created.

### Method

This I do by not creating a directory, when no type with the namespace exists, instead keep the `.` where it is.

```
split all namespaces into their segments
for each unique namespace in namespaces
  for each segment in namespace, index i
    list all namespaces where segments are equal as shared
    if shared has lost namespaces compared to previous shared
      for each namespace[i] previous shared
        replace '.' with '\\' 
      replace '.' with '\\' in namespace[i]
    set previous shared to shared
  add namespace to namespaces
```

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] namespaces = new[] { // Set namespaces from types
            "Root.Sub11.Sub11.Sub3",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub11",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub12",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14.Sub47",
        };
        /* Should result in this list of directories:
         * Root.Sub11/Sub11/Sub3
         * Root.Sub11/Sub11
         * Root.Sub11/Sub21
         * Root.Sub11/Sub21/Sub12
         * Root.Sub11/Sub21/Sub13.Sub14
         * Root.Sub11/Sub21/Sub13.Sub14/Sub47
         */
        NamespacesToDirectoryStructure(namespaces.Select(n => n.Split(".")));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var dir in typeNamespaceToPathMap.Values)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(new string(dir));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
    
    private static readonly IDictionary<string[], char[]> typeNamespaceToPathMap = new Dictionary<string[], char[]>();

    private static void NamespacesToDirectoryStructure(IEnumerable<string[]> namespaces)
    {
        IList<string[]> processedTypeNamespaces = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (string[] segments in namespaces
                 .Distinct(new StringSequenceEqualityComparer())
                 .OrderBy(n => n.Length))
        {
            int segment = 0;
            char[] path = string.Join('.', segments).ToCharArray();
            IList<int> sharedNamespacePortionIndices;
            IList<string[]> sharedNamespacePortions = processedTypeNamespaces;
            do
            {
                // All namespaces, that share the segment and all previous with this.
                sharedNamespacePortionIndices = IndexOfAll(sharedNamespacePortions, segments, segment).ToList();
                if (segment != 0)
                {
                    // All namespaces, that share all previous segments with this.
                    IList<int> indices = sharedNamespacePortionIndices;
                    IEnumerable<string[]> removedNamespaces = TakeWhere(sharedNamespacePortions, (i, x) => !indices.Contains(i));
                    if (removedNamespaces.Any())
                    {
                        // Convert the [.] to [\] to indicate a path branching for all that share previous segments
                        int charIndex = segments.Take(segment).Select(s => s.Length).Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x + y + 1) - 1;
                        path[charIndex] = '\\';
                        foreach (char[] value in typeNamespaceToPathMap
                                 .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Length > charIndex && (ReferenceEquals(kvp.Key, segments) || sharedNamespacePortions.Contains(kvp.Key)))
                                 .Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
                        {
                            value[charIndex] = '\\';
                        }
                    }

                }
                sharedNamespacePortions = TakeWhere(sharedNamespacePortions, (i, x) => sharedNamespacePortionIndices.Contains(i)).ToList();
                segment++;
            } while (segment < segments.Length && sharedNamespacePortions.Count > 0);

            processedTypeNamespaces.Add(segments);
            typeNamespaceToPathMap.Add(segments, path);
        }
    }

    // Enumerates all items of the collection where the segment is equal to the segment at the same position - specified by segment - in test.
    private static IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll(IList<string[]> collection, string[] test, int segment)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < collection.Count; index++)
        {
            if (collection[index].Length > segment && String.Equals(test[segment], collection[index][segment], StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                yield return index;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string[]> TakeWhere(IList<string[]> collection, Func<int, string[], bool> predicate)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(i, collection[i]))
            {
                yield return collection[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private class StringSequenceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
        {
            if (x is null || x.Length != y?.Length)
                return false;
            for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!x[i].Equals(y[i], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string[] obj) => obj.GetHashCode(true);
    }
}

///<summary>Source: https://github.com/ProphetLamb-Organistion/Groundbeef/blob/master/src/Collections/Collections/CollectionHashing.cs</summary>
public static class CollectionHashing
{
    public static int GetHashCode(this IList list, bool fromValues)
    {
        if (list is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
        if (!fromValues)
            return list.GetHashCode();
        int length = list.Count;
        if (length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(list), "List cannot be empty");
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            object value = list[i] ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Value cannot be null");
            c = CombineHashCodes(c, value.GetHashCode());
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2)
    {
        return ((h1 << 5) + h1) ^ h2;
    }
}
```

Code on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eh1znD)

### Problem

While the code above works perfectly fine, the algorithm is redicolusily expensive and has way to much memory overhead for my liking. But I am at the end of my wits in regards to optimizing this code, while intuitively the desired behaviour **should** be achievable with much less computational effort. So I feel like I am missing something important here.

### Question

So I need all the opinions I can get

- A: on how to optimize my existing code, or
- B: on a fundamentally different approach to the problem, that yields a simplier solution.

Thanks in advance, and happy coding!

Edit: Fix `Distinct`-clause: implement `IEqualityComparer<>.GetHashCode`, and loose trust in `IEnumerable<>.SequenceEquals`.

Comment: 2 questions: why does "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14.Sub47" not go to "Root.Sub11/Sub21/Sub13.Sub14.Sub47", is there a limit of one "." per folder name? Would a solution that only returns unique directories be acceptable? e.g. you currently have 3 "Root.Sub11/Sub21/Sub13.Sub14" returned.

Comment: @RobH Good point. And indeed the code should do exactly as you suggest in the `Distinct`-clause. But I had to implement a custom `GetHashCode`-function, because `Distinct`first checks `GetHashCode`. See updated [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eh1znDl) file

Comment: I don't see why you have "Root.Sub11" and "Sub13.Sub14" as directory names, other than because some random rule says so. Why indulge such inconsistent behavior? What if your list changes in the future and breaks the current directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify the problem by splitting it into two parts. Part one, build a tree structure to hold your data. Part two, take the tree and spit out your paths. I knocked up a very quick example below.

```
// A simple, specialised node class for your tree
class Node
{
    public bool Ends { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    
    public List<Node> Children { get; private set; } = new List<Node>();

    private Node GetOrAddChild(string value)
    {
        var child = Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == value);
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = new Node { Value = value };
            Children.Add(child);
        }
        return child;
    }

    public void AddPath(string path) => AddPath(this, path);

    public static void AddPath(Node n, string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return;
            
        var idx = path.IndexOf(".");
        if (idx == -1)
        {
            var child = n.GetOrAddChild(path);
            child.Ends = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var part = path.Substring(0, idx);
            var child = n.GetOrAddChild(part);
            AddPath(child, path.Substring(idx + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Using this, you then create your tree with your data:

```
void Main()
{
    // build the tree
    Node root = new Node();
    string[] namespaces = new[] {
            "Root.Sub11.Sub11.Sub3",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub11",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub12",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14",
            "Root.Sub11.Sub21.Sub13.Sub14.Sub47",
        };
    foreach (var ns in namespaces)
    {
        root.AddPath(ns);
    }

    // Use the tree:
    GetDirectories(root).ToList();
}
```

Now that you have a tree of unique paths, one simply walks the tree:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(Node n)
{
    if (n.Ends)
    {
        yield return n.Value;
    }
    var separator = n.Children.Count == 1 && !n.Ends ? "." : "/";
    foreach (var c in n.Children)
    foreach (var path in GetDirectories(c))
    {
        yield return n.Value == null
            ? path
            : $"{n.Value}{separator}{path}";
    }
}
```

I haven't checked the performance of this code but I believe it is easier to follow what's happening. Because of that, you can also further specialize the tree structure e.g. store the children in an `IDictionary<string, Node>` instead of using lists to speed things up by changing the `FirstOrDefault` to `TryGetValue`.

I find this two step approach a useful pattern when an algorithm is getting overly complex. It's usually a sign that I haven't got a suitable data structure to work with and introducing one can simplify the implementation a lot. A nice side-effect is that you can easily add other formatters to spit out XML, HTML, mkdir commands, or whatever you need without having to change the core algorithm.

Comment: Based on your answer I created a [tree class](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZhWyL). Thanks a lot! I still would like to convert the GetDirectories into an iterative algorithm, but thats of little matter.